# Web-based asset manager

Tags: web-apps, self-hosted, asset-management

I am looking for an (preferably open source) web based asset manager with the following features:

- Download and upload files (images/video/audio/documents)
- Create different categories
- Create users and assign permissions (not all users should be allowed to upload)
- Ability to post news / blog posts
- Social feed either Twitter or Facebook

Nice to have but not necessary:

- Ability to use Azure for file storage

Is it not a problem if it is not free though I prefer an open source solution so I can customise it in the future if necessary.

Preferred technology is either ASP.NET or PHP (simply because I am familiar with those).

My intention is to use this software to create a community website.

So far I found:

- http://www.filerun.com/ - will require to build a website around this for posting news, and adding social media feeds, only problem is that it's not open source.

**UPDATE:**

Ended up going with wordpress and this plugin https://www.joomunited.com/wordpress-demo/wp-file-download/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently, I asked a similar question about cataloging a collection, but it had very similar requirements.  It was recommended to use Drupal.  I set up a Drupal site in a few minutes, and then I customized the content types very quickly.

I suggest looking at [**Drupal**](https://www.drupal.org/) because:

- It has built-in photos, and with the right module you can do all kinds of uploads.
- Different categories can be implemented with different content types or simply with a field that specifies which category something's in.
- It has user permissions that allow different content types for different users or roles.
- News and blog posts are built-in.
- "Social feed either Twitter or Facebook" - I've never done this, but I see multiple modules for this.
- "Ability to use Azure for file storage" - Again, I've not done this, but there is a module for Azure storage.
- It's based on PHP.

Comment: Thank you, your solution does seem to fit the bill. I have been looking at wordpress as well which offers similar functionality. Leaving the question open for a bit longer because i am still hoping for a out of the box solution.